Different parametrizations of squared exponential kernel
Suppose $u, v \in \mathbb R^d$, where $u = (u_1, \dots, u_d)$ and $v = (v_1, \dots, v_d)$. This paper (pp. 7--8) defines the squared exponential (or Gaussian) correlation function to be
$$
\rho(u, v) = \exp\left(-\sum_{j = 1}^d \frac{(u_j - v_j)^2}{2\theta_j^2}\right). \tag{1}
$$
(I am using slightly different notation than the paper uses.)
This other paper (p. 367) defines the kernel to be
$$
\rho'(u, v) = \exp\left(-\sum_{j = 1}^d \theta'_j (u_j - v_j)^2\right). \tag{2}
$$
(Again I use slightly different notation.)
I am hoping for a sanity check regarding converting from the parametrization as in $(1)$ to $(2)$. Suppose I fit a Gaussian process model in $\mathbb R^2$ using the kernel as in $(1)$, and I get back that $\theta_1 = 2$ and $\theta_2 = 3$. If I want to analyze these values from the perspective of $(2)$, I think can just note that $\theta'_j = 1/(2\theta_j^2)$, so that I would get $\theta'_1 = 1/(2 \cdot 2^2) = 1/8$ and $\theta'_2 = 1/(2 \cdot 3^2) = 1/18$.
Is that right? I appreciate any help.

Yes, that is correct!
